# Replace all non numeric characters by only one word

Tags: java, regex

I want to do the next replacement:

WORD1234 -> W1234

So, I'm using the regex:

```
([^\d]*)([0-9]+)([^\d]*)
```

Replacement: `W$2`

If the word is WORD1234AAAAA, using the previous regex I have the same result: W1234, which is what I want.

But if the word is `WO12RD34` the result I have is: `W12W34`

What I want basically in all the cases is to remove all non-numeric characters and add the letter W at the beginning.

### Update:

The input string does not always start with a `W`. It can be for example `ABC12DE34` and the desired result is: `FA1234`. Meaning, remove all non-numeric characters and add a word at the beginning.

Comment: Please share what the tool/programming language is.

Comment: _"to remove all non-numeric characters and add the letter W at the beginning"_ Why don't you simply use `\D+`, replace with an empty string, and then insert the letter `W` at the beginning of your output string.

Comment: @AhmedAbdelhameed You assume OP has access to the actual code, and we do not know that, that is why I asked what the used tool/environment is.

Comment: I'm using Java but both regex and replace patterns are stored in database. I have to do it in only one replaceAll statement. I can't use additional java code, it has to be: String result = word.replaceAll(regex,replacement);

Comment: Does your input string always start with `W`?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
String regex = "(?<start>^W)|(\\D)";
String replacement = "${start}";

System.out.println("WO12RD34".replaceAll(regex, replacement)); //prints W1234
System.out.println("WORD1234AAAAA".replaceAll(regex, replacement)); //prints W1234
```

With this regex, the "start" capturing group will only be set when the first character is matched. Otherwise, it will be empty.

The idea is that, when the start of the string followed by W is matched, the named "start" pattern would be initialised to ^W. Then, just replace ^W with itself.

Otherwise, when any non-digit character is matched, then the start pattern will not be set (and be empty). Then, also replace the non-digit character with nothing.

Comment: This is great but it does not have to start with the beginning of the word. I mean:

I want to convert WO12RD34 to FA1234

I need to remove all non-numeric characters and add some letters at the beginning, in this case FA.

Comment: @JavierGarcía I don't think what you're trying to do would be possible with one regex and that's why I deleted my answer after you clarified the requirement. Honestly, I don't see any reason why you _have to_ use one regex. If you're getting your replacement string from a database, what prevents you from inserting it at the beginning of the string like I mentioned in the comments above?

Comment: Because what I take from the database is the replacement expression, not the first characters. I mean FA$2, for example. For now, I have to do the replacement I mention above but in the future the requirement could change. The idea is to change only the data of the DB and no modify the java code.

Comment: @JavierGarcía Well, you'll probably have to start thinking about alternatives. For example, you could split the "replacement" column in the database into two columns, one for the preceding "word" and one for the pattern or keep it as one column and split the value using some kind of a delimiter. There are plenty of ways to get around this. Regex is not a magic tool which should be expected to solve any problem solely.